# Javascript - Get index of penultimate occurrence of a string?

Tags: javascript, string, lastindexof

I have this string:

> IESA1V1Ent/Cuerpo/Asiento:1/DatosRepercusion/REP_NUMDocumentoIdent/

How can I get the index of the penultimate `/`?

IESA1V1Ent/Cuerpo/Asiento:1/DatosRepercusion **Index Of->/** REP_NUMDocumentoIdent/

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the second last index by taking the last index as value for the searching.

```js
var string = 'IESA1V1Ent/Cuerpo/Asiento:1/DatosRepercusion/REP_NUMDocumentoIdent/',
    index = string.lastIndexOf('/', string.lastIndexOf('/') - 1);

console.log(index);
console.log(string.slice(index));
```